# Unable to load spacy English model - 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I installed spacy using pip and then downloaded the English model using 

`$ python -m spacy download en`
which after downloading gave me the message

`You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')`

Using IPython,

`import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en')`

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a32b6d2b36d8> in <module>()
----> 1 nlp=spacy.load('en')

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.pyc in load(n
ame, **overrides)
     13     from .deprecated import resolve_load_name
     14     name = resolve_load_name(name, **overrides)
---> 15     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     16
     17

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.pyc in load_model
(name, **overrides)
    102     if isinstance(name, basestring_):
    103         if name in set([d.name for d in data_path.iterdir()]): # in data
 dir / shortcut
--> 104             return load_model_from_link(name, **overrides)
    105         if is_package(name): # installed as package
    106             return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.pyc in load_model
_from_link(name, **overrides)
    121             "Cant' load '%s'. If you're using a shortcut link, make sure
 it "
    122             "points to a valid model package (not just a data directory)
." % name)
--> 123     return cls.load(**overrides)
    124
    125

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en\__init__.pyc i
n load(**overrides)
     10
     11 def load(**overrides):
---> 12     return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.pyc in load_model
_from_init_py(init_file, **overrides)
    165     if not model_path.exists():
    166         raise ValueError("Can't find model directory: %s" % path2str(dat
a_path))
--> 167     return load_model_from_path(data_path, meta, **overrides)
    168
    169

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.pyc in load_model
_from_path(model_path, meta, **overrides)
    148             component = nlp.create_pipe(name, config=config)
    149             nlp.add_pipe(component, name=name)
--> 150     return nlp.from_disk(model_path)
    151
    152

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.pyc in from_d
isk(self, path, disable)
    571         if not (path / 'vocab').exists():
    572             exclude['vocab'] = True
--> 573         util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
    574         return self
    575

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.pyc in from_disk(
path, readers, exclude)
    495     for key, reader in readers.items():
    496         if key not in exclude:
--> 497             reader(path / key)
    498     return path
    499

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.pyc in <lambd
a>(p)
    558         path = util.ensure_path(path)
    559         deserializers = OrderedDict((
--> 560             ('vocab', lambda p: self.vocab.from_disk(p)),
    561             ('tokenizer', lambda p: self.tokenizer.from_disk(p, vocab=Fa
lse)),
    562             ('meta.json', lambda p: p.open('w').write(json_dumps(self.me
ta)))

vocab.pyx in spacy.vocab.Vocab.from_disk()

vectors.pyx in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk()

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.pyc in from_disk(
path, readers, exclude)
    495     for key, reader in readers.items():
    496         if key not in exclude:
--> 497             reader(path / key)
    498     return path
    499

vectors.pyx in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk.load_keys()

C:\Users\PARVATHY SARAT\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in load(
file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    389         _ZIP_PREFIX = asbytes('PK\x03\x04')
    390         N = len(format.MAGIC_PREFIX)
--> 391         magic = fid.read(N)
    392         fid.seek(-N, 1)  # back-up
    393         if magic.startswith(_ZIP_PREFIX):

AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I have the English model files(en_core_web_sm) downloaded to the working directory, am I missing something? Do I need to set a path variable? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anybody else receives this error : I opened this as an [issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1421) with spaCy's developers on Github. I was suggested using Python 3.6 instead of 2.7 for the moment as there is no alternate workaround to the problem. The next spaCy version should cover this bugfix (I'm told).

Comment: similar problem with Py3.5  in anaconda environment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is glitch involving language downloads in anaconda environments. Here is the pending pull request
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/1792